the trait bound `solana_sdk::pubkey::Pubkey: BorshDeserialize` is not satisfied the following other types implement trait `BorshDeserialize`:
Error:
the trait bound `solana_sdk::pubkey::Pubkey: BorshDeserialize` is not satisfied the following other types implement trait `BorshDeserialize`:
Pubkey code:
#[cfg_attr(target_arch = "wasm32", wasm_bindgen)]
#[repr(transparent)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "frozen-abi", derive(AbiExample))]
#[cfg_attr(
    feature = "borsh",
    derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, BorshSchema),
    borsh(crate = "borsh")
)]
#[derive(
    Clone,
    Copy,
    Default,
    Deserialize,
    Eq,
    Hash,
    Ord,
    PartialEq,
    PartialOrd,
    Pod,
    Serialize,
    Zeroable,
)]
#[cfg_attr(test, derive(Arbitrary))]
pub struct Pubkey(pub(crate) [u8; 32]);


You may need to enable the borsh feature on the solana-program crate, or you may be using an unsupported version of borsh. It's hard to tell without the code that's triggering the issue
